# Floating button is not adjusted in center of app bar in some devices

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-appbarlayout

[image: Image Link]

I have provided the screenshot of my app screen. You can see that the floating button ( in this case i used Image Button and provided my image) is not showing full i.e. its half part is behind the app bar, the app bar is in green color. Although this same FAB button is showing full in some devices and versions like 4.2, 4.3 but not showing full on some devices and my version 5.0 and up.

Following is my code for this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/app_bar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="190dp"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:background="@drawable/cvr1"
  app:expanded="true">
  <!--android:theme="?attr/customAppBarOverlay"-->


<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="snap">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
      android:background="@null"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/add_fab"
  android:background="@drawable/starts"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
  app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
  app:elevation="0dp"
  app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
  />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I dont know what exactly is the issue. I checked on internet but found same solutions like these lines but still not showing full

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
```

Please Help!

Comment: instead of fixed margin try `layout_centerVertical="true"` and `layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Comment: No it doesn't work :(

Comment: try it with relative layout

Comment: with relative layout? i didn't understand this sir, i did not used relative layout

Answer (score 0):

The **best practice** is to use the **F A B** (Floating Action Bar) provided in the support library.

Add this to build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

And inside the `CoordinatorLayout` try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

This should produce the FAB as provided in the below image:

[image]

In order to change the position of the `FAB` , you can change:

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

to the preferred way for the ideal position in your layout.

Comment: I tried this but still it doesn't works, half of the FAB button still hidden behind app bar layout

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you are using `app:elevation="0dp"` on your button. As the `AppBarLayout` has default elevation of 4dp, on lollipop devices and higher, the button will be drawn under it.